# Android Image view does not get updated

Tags: android, firebase, android-imageview, picasso

I have a code segment to update the profile image in an app.

When I update that, my image is not visible in the image view. But the firebase gets updates with the new image.

Can someone help me with this?

Below is my code to update the firebase.

```
if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                loadingBar.setTitle("Set Profile Image");
                loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait!");
                loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                loadingBar.show();

                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

                StorageReference filePath = userProfileImageReference.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");
                filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Profile Image Uploaded Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                            rootRef.child(currentUserID).child("Image")
                                    .setValue(downloadUrl)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Image saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                String message = task.getException().toString();
                                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                        else {
                            String message = task.getException().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Here is my code to save the image in the app.

```
private void retrieveUserInformation() {
        rootRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if ((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("Name") && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("ProfileImage")))) {
                    String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                    String retrieveProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("ProfileImage").getValue().toString();

                    username.setText(retrieveUserName);
                    Picasso.get().load(retrieveProfileImage).into(userProfileImage);
                }
                else if ((dataSnapshot.exists()) && (dataSnapshot.hasChild("Name"))) {
                    String retrieveUserName = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();

                    username.setText(retrieveUserName);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Please update your profile information...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happening because your image size is too big, That's why its taking time to downloading the image from storage.

Try resizing your image before Upload to  firebase Storage.